# hash sum mismatch for apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

```
    Fetched 6.135 kB in 19s (321 kB/s)                                             
    Reading package lists... Done
    E: Failed to fetch http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
    E: Failed to fetch http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.gz  
    E: Failed to fetch http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
    E: Failed to fetch http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.gz  
    E: Failed to fetch http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
    E: Failed to fetch http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
    E: Failed to fetch http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: just try after a while something may have gone wrong this time,
Also it helps to not just post the terminal output, but also what you tried to solve etc.

Answer (score 4):

Many a times, when HTTP is used for update and sometimes mirrors may change, therefore this problem may occur. You will have to remove downloaded repository information from the `/var/lib/apt/lists/` directory. To remove the information, open the `terminal` and type

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Once, the files is removed, you can continue with the update using the command

```
sudo apt update
```