# Apt Hash Sum mismatch when I try to do and Update

Tags: apt, updates

When I try to run an update I get this error

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/76a1d961a2306c3e94f119eee121a77da780b8d9f98ec45e9b6a76c5dd40b2a3  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:686028 [weak]
    - SHA256:76a1d961a2306c3e94f119eee121a77da780b8d9f98ec45e9b6a76c5dd40b2a3
    - SHA1:ff6fb009d5e2e19a0c924bb5f4a2d4f02c629e26 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:4469774a13ddbd466922a2bb09a42710 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:4bbe1b9216e4a4f5b7e3e90b47f68c9a6d6705bc86313f440b52d2ef7f3b765a
    - SHA1:b94cb236ec50a2f6fa69de476b247c822b74dd95 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:64a72e5fb7d55a4a3c60f0916abcc24e [weak]
    - Filesize:686028 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 04 Nov 2020 20:18:42 +0000
   Release file created at: Wed, 04 Nov 2020 21:56:32 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I have answered the question here   https://askubuntu.com/a/1192523/890892